# Assign result of <select> in Smarty variable

Tags: php, variables, smarty, prestashop

I have a list field:

```
<select name="choix_magasin" id="choixmag">
  <option value="0" selected>--</option>
   {foreach $stores as $store}
  <option value="{$store.id_store}">{$store.city}</option>
   {/foreach}
</select>
```

I want to assign the result of this list in a smarty variable and I want to use my variable in any PHP files of my website. How is it possible ?

Comment: What does "the result of this list" mean?

Comment: My list display several cities (that I import from my database), so for example, she displays : - New York -Los Angeles etc.... The customer must select an option and I want to keep his choice in a variable (result or id).

Comment: You just want to assign a client chosen city and its id, not the entire cities list?

Answer (score 0):

You can then store the result in the Cookie, and you have it on all the site.

Regards,

Arthur

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think it's better. But I can't to register my cookie. In my controller : $this->context->cookie->__set('choix_magasin',$resultat); It doesn't work.

Comment: try :
$cookie = new Cookie("choix_magasin");
$context = Context::getContext();
$cookie->__set('choix_magasin', $resultat);